# Select condition + another condition depending on the ordered result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    date      action 
----------   -------
2018-01-12   acquire
2018-01-14   release
2018-01-15   acquire
2018-01-19   release
```

And I need to SELECT WHERE date>='2018-01-13' but only from some 'acquire' row (ordered by date ASC) so the result would be

```
2018-01-15   acquire
2018-01-19   release
```

(from the first acquire after the date condition is met). Is it possible with a single SQL sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the minimum date that meets the condition, then select all rows with dates starting from that.

```
SELECT date, action
FROM yourTable
WHERE date >= (
    SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE date >= '2018-01-13' AND action = 'acquire'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.date <= a.date 
 WHERE b.date >= '2018-01-13' 
   AND b.action = 'acquire';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to get the first date for each action ...

```
SELECT `date`, `action`
FROM theTable
WHERE (`date`, `action`) IN (
   SELECT MIN(`date`), `action`
   FROM theTable
   WHERE `date` > '2018-01-13'
   GROUP BY `action`
)
```